Is "tandem tamen" a classical paronym?
I've noted the use of the expression tandem tamen (~ in the end however, but yet, and yet), in various Latin texts. It's a paronym that appears in many post-classical and neo-Latin texts; by example :

Alciato, Emblemata (1584) : sic vera & iusta quanquam cedant interdum violentis hominum iniuriis, tandem tamen emergunt.
Ritchie's fabulae faciles, §4 : Diū per āera uolābat; tandem tamen ad eum locum uēnit ubi Medūsa cum cēterīs Gorgōnibus habitābat.

By the way, tamen tandem doesn't exist at all.
I expected to find this expression in classical authors. To my great surprise, this site lists only two occurrences, namely Publius Terentius Afer, Phormio 630 and C. Plinius Caecilius Secundus, Panegyricus 60.4.2.
I also find the absence of this expression in dactylic hexameters disconcerting, since tandem tamen provides "- - u u" as rhythmic pattern, which is suitable for dactylic hexameter.
The example taken from Terence shows that this expression also adapts well to the iambic sennary :

(Phormio.630) | Vērum | pōn(e) es|se vīc|t(um) eum; at | tandem |
tamen |

The expression tandem tamen could therefore have a place in Latin verse and prose: so why is it so rare? It's as if classical Latin avoided this paronymy. Is this conclusion correct? What explanation could be given for this avoidance?

"*tamen tandem" doesn't exist because https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tamen#Latin is postpositive

Any given expression is only going to have so many attestations in a limited corpus. The fact that you found two is evidence that it wasn't proscribed; I'm not sure there is much more to say.

@Cairnarvon Moreover, the fact that it's found in both Terence and Pliny suggest it's acceptable to Latin grammar as a whole. It might just not be a common phrase to say, but there's nothing wrong with it.

tamen is not normally used with tandem because they both have the sense of "finally" so it would sound repetitive to a Roman, like you were repeating the same idea. For the same reason, you do not find tamen in conjunction with other ordinal adverbs or conjunctions that have the same conclusive idea. For example,
Not found:
ergo tamen
igitur tamen
deinde tamen
vero tamen
autem tamen
denique tamen
demum tamen
So, to the English mind all of these expressions are fine because our idea of "nevertheless" does not imply finality. For example, in English we can say "At last nevertheless they arrived" and transverbalize this as denique tamen pervenerunt but you would never find this in classical Latin because denique and tamen are ideologically redundant. In other words, to a Roman it would sound as though you said, "At last nevertheless at last they arrived" which is (possibly?) grammatical, but seems weird and awkward.
Note that you could use a word like postremo, though, because it does not imply finality, but continuing action. For example, postremo tamen pervenerunt would sound like "Eventually nevertheless at last they arrived".
The issue here is that words have shades of meaning and implied context that do not always translate directly into English. Why does it seem ok to a Roman to write postremo tamen... but not demum tamen...? The answer is the words have contextual implications that are not present in their English translations.

If tandem tamen would have sounded repetitive to a Roman, how do you explain its prevalence in later Latin?

@Cairnarvon Because those are people for whom Latin was a second language and they lacked the intuitive thought processes that were native to the original Quirites. Language is an expression of thought and if a person's mentality is Greek or Numidian or whatever, then they do not have a Roman mentality, they have a Greek mentality.
